# Number of extensions of a place

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $L/K$ be a separable extension (not necessarily normal). Let $v \in K$ be a place of $K$ and let $W_{v}$ be the set of places of $L$ extending $v$. In a remark in Algebraic Number Theory by Neukirch, page 171, says the following:

Let $M$ be the normal closure of $L$ over $K$. Let $G=Gal(M/K)$ and $H=Gal(M/L)$. Let $\omega$ me any place extending $v$ to $M$. Let $G_{\omega}=G_{\omega}(M/K)$ be the corresponding decomposition group. Then, there is a bijection:

$$ G_{\omega} \setminus G / H \rightarrow W_{v}$$

given by $G_{\omega} \sigma H \mapsto \omega \circ \sigma |L$, where
$G_{\omega} \setminus G / H$ is the set of double cosets $G_{\omega} \sigma H$. Thus, the number of extensions of $v$ to $L$ is the number of those cosets.

I understand why this map is surjective but I am not able to prove injectivity. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have found this question in this site
[Double cosets (Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742263/double-cosets-neukirchs-algebraic-number-theory)
but I am not sure how to do it for general places. Moreover, why are the cosets swapped? Does it even matter?

Comment: Anything unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L = K(a)\cong K[x]/(f)$,

$v$ is a place of $K$,

Factorize in irreducibles $f = \prod_j f_j \in K_v[x]$

Let $M$ be the Galois closure of $L/K$ and $G = Gal(M/K),H=Gal(M/L),G_\omega = Gal(M_\omega/K_v)$ where $\omega$ extends $v$ to $M$, viewed as a subfield of $M_\omega$.

$G$ acts transitively on the roots of $f$, the stabilizer of $a$ is $H$,
$G_\omega$ acts transitively on the roots of each $f_j$.

For each $j$ take some $g_j\in G$ such that $f_j(g_j(a))=0$. Then
$$f_j = \prod_{b\in G_\omega g_j(a)} (x-b)=
\prod_{b\in G_\omega g_j H(a)} (x-b)\in M_\omega[x]
$$

$f_j(g(a))=0$ iff $g_\omega g(a)=g_j(a)$ for some $g_\omega\in G_\omega$ iff $g_\omega g\in g_j H$. So $$G_\omega g_j H = \{ g\in G, f_j(g(a))=0\}$$

ie. each $f_j$ corresponds to the double coset $G_\omega g_j H$.

The places of $L$ extending $v$ correspond to the $f_j$.

Comment: Hi, I do not understand the line $f_j(g(a)) = 0 \iff g_{\omega}g(a)=g_j(a)$ for some $g_{\omega} \in G_{\omega} \iff g_{\omega}g \in g_jH$. I do not understand either why that proves the equality of sets below. Could you give some more detail?

Comment: The first $\iff$ is that $G_\omega$ acts transitively on the roots of $f_j$. The second one is saying that $g_j^{-1} g_\omega g$ fixes $a$ so it fixes $K(a)$.

Comment: Ok. How do you conclude that the f_j correspond to the cosests then?

Comment: $G_\omega g_j H = \{ g\in G, f_j(g(a))=0\}$

Comment: Well, I do not understand why that equality implies the correspondence.

Comment: Really? Like every element of this coset is a root, and the previous line proves that every root is element of this coset..

Comment: Likely that you don't understand that $G_\omega$ sends a root of $f_j$ to a root of $f_j$ and it does so transitively.

Comment: Yes, I think it is clear now. Thank you very much for your patience :)